# Different output of code in command line and browser

Tags: browser, lua, output

I have an embedded linux, buildroot. I have to use pmbus_peek commands, that's why I need /dev/i2c-0. I do it with lua code from the browser, nginx is the server. Lua code is appended, nginx.conf too. If I use the command line "lua test.lua" then I get the same result as "ls -1 /dev/*". If I use the browser line "http://192.168.xxx.yyy/test.lua" a lot of items are lost, for instance "dev/i2c-0". Why there are different outputs, where is the i2c-0 item?
The "test.lua" is for use in lua directly, if you use it with the browser remove the uncomment marks in lines 6 and 7.

test.lua:

```
function test ()
    local res ={}
    local f = io.popen("ls -1 /dev/*")
    for line in f:lines() do
        if line ~= nil then
--               ngx.log( ngx.ERR, "result: "..line )
--               ngx.say( "result: "..line.."<br>" )
                print( "result: " ..line )
        end
    end
    f:close() 
    return res
end

local function main()
  local result = test()
end

main()
```

nginx.conf:

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  warn;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    
    log_format upstream_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                             '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                             '"$http_referer" [$request_body]'
                             'rt=$request_time {$query_string} {$request_body_file}'
                             '$request_completion';
  
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_time;
    
    server {
            listen       80 default_server;
            location     /test {
                                ssi on;
                                root   /usr/local/;
                                # MIME type determined by default_type:
                                default_type 'text/html';
                                
                                content_by_lua_file /usr/local/test.lua;
                                }
            }
}
```

Comment: What does `sudo -u nobody lua /usr/local/test.lua` show (or some other way to run the script with the same permissions as nginx)?

Comment: It' the same result. In nginx.conf the first line could also be "user  nobody;". It doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, I ment "user root;".